# If is not working in If-elseif statement

Tags: forms, powershell, if-statement, checkbox, conditional-statements

Im writing a code which asks the user to mark certain files that he wants and then it creates a file and changes it accordingly, just wrote hello for now.

The problem is that it only works in the `if` section, and not in the `else if`. I couldn't find an answer online.

Here is my code:

```
 [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
 [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName    ("System.Windows.Forms") 

 #This creates the path for the Json
 New-Item c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents -ItemType directory -Name Json

 #creating the form
 $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
 $objForm.Text = "Ofir`s script"
 $objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(270,200) 
 $objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

 #creating the label
 $objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
 $objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
 $objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
 $objLabel.Text = "Please check the relevant boxes:"
 $objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel)

 #This creates a checkbox called dsp.z
 $objDspCheckbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox 
 $objDspCheckbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
 $objDspCheckbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,20)
 $objDspCheckbox.Text = "dsp.z"
 $objDspCheckbox.TabIndex = 0
 $objForm.Controls.Add($objDspCheckbox)

 #This creates a checkbox called fpga.bin
 $objFpgaCheckbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox 
 $objFpgaCheckbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,60) 
 $objFpgaCheckbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,20)
 $objFpgaCheckbox.Text = "fpga.bin"
 $objFpgaCheckbox.TabIndex = 1
 $objForm.Controls.Add($objFpgaCheckbox)

 #This creates a checkbox called bootrom_uncmp.bin
 $objBootCheckbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox 
 $objBootCheckbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,80) 
 $objBootCheckbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,20)
 $objBootCheckbox.Text = "bootrom_uncmp.bin"
 $objBootCheckbox.TabIndex = 2
 $objForm.Controls.Add($objBootCheckbox)

 #ok Button 
 $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
 $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(40,120)
 $OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
 $OKButton.Text = "OK"
 $OKButton.Add_Click({if ($objDspCheckbox.Checked -eq $true)
 {
 New-Item c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json -itemtype file -name file.json -value "Hello" ;$objForm.close()}
 }
 )

 elseif ($objFpgaCheckbox.Checked -eq $true)
 {
 New-Item c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json -itemtype file -name file.json -value "Hello2" ;$objForm.close()
 }

 elseif ($objBootCheckbox.Checked -eq $true)
 {
 New-Item c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json -itemtype file -name file.json -value "Hello3" ;$objForm.close()
 }

 $objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)



 #cancle Button
 $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
 $CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,120)
 $CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
 $CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
 $CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
 $objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)


 #makes the form appear on top of the screen
 $objForm.Topmost = $True

 $objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
 [void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Check it. You're closing the `if-loop` here only:  `$OKButton.Add_Click({if ...} )`

Comment: i dont understand. i only have "{" in the if statement so this is the only place i need to close.. no? as i saw online the structure of else if is "else if (condition) {action}

Comment: I mean `)` should be after `else-if` right?

Comment: @ofribouba From the question it sounds like you want to test all three checkboxes independently. If so, change your `else if` clauses to `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine now with the **elseif** . I have made few improvements like if the json folder is already existing then it was throwing error . So I am checking on prior that if the folder is already there then do not create or overwrite. Use that same folder and create the Json file under that. If the folder is not present then only create it.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
 [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

 #This creates the path for the Json and also check if it is already there.
 If(!(Test-Path -Path C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json))
 {
 New-Item c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents -ItemType directory -Name Json
 }
 #creating the form
 $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
 $objForm.Text = "Ofir`s script"
 $objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(270,200) 
 $objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

 #creating the label
 $objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
 $objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
 $objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
 $objLabel.Text = "Please check the relevant boxes:"
 $objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel)

 #This creates a checkbox called dsp.z
 $objDspCheckbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox 
 $objDspCheckbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
 $objDspCheckbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,20)
 $objDspCheckbox.Text = "dsp.z"
 $objDspCheckbox.TabIndex = 0
 $objForm.Controls.Add($objDspCheckbox)

 #This creates a checkbox called fpga.bin
 $objFpgaCheckbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox 
 $objFpgaCheckbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,60) 
 $objFpgaCheckbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,20)
 $objFpgaCheckbox.Text = "fpga.bin"
 $objFpgaCheckbox.TabIndex = 1
 $objForm.Controls.Add($objFpgaCheckbox)

 #This creates a checkbox called bootrom_uncmp.bin
 $objBootCheckbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox 
 $objBootCheckbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,80) 
 $objBootCheckbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,20)
 $objBootCheckbox.Text = "bootrom_uncmp.bin"
 $objBootCheckbox.TabIndex = 2
 $objForm.Controls.Add($objBootCheckbox)

 #ok Button 
 $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
 $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(40,120)
 $OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
 $OKButton.Text = "OK"
 $OKButton.Add_Click(
    {
    if($objDspCheckbox.Checked -eq $true)
        {
            New-Item c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json -itemtype file -name file.json -value "Hello" ;$objForm.close()
        }

    elseif($objFpgaCheckbox.Checked -eq $true)
        {
            New-Item c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json -itemtype file -name file.json -value "Hello2" ;$objForm.close()
        }
    elseif($objBootCheckbox.Checked -eq $true)
        {
            New-Item c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json -itemtype file -name file.json -value "Hello3" ;$objForm.close()
        }
    }
    )


 $objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)



 #cancle Button
 $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
 $CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,120)
 $CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
 $CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
 $CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
 $objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)


 #makes the form appear on top of the screen
 $objForm.Topmost = $True

 $objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
 [void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: thats great! thanks for the improvments and the help!

Comment: @ofribouba . Please accept the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You have a curly-bracket in this line:

```
New-Item c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json -itemtype file -name file.json -value "Hello" ;$objForm.close()}
```

So change the click handler to:

```
$OKButton.Add_Click(
 {
     if ($objDspCheckbox.Checked -eq $true)
     {
        New-Item c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json -itemtype file -name file.json -value "Hello" ;$objForm.close()
     }

     elseif ($objFpgaCheckbox.Checked -eq $true)
     {
        New-Item c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json -itemtype file -name file.json -value "Hello2" ;$objForm.close()
     }

     elseif ($objBootCheckbox.Checked -eq $true)
     {
        New-Item c:\users\$env:USERNAME\documents\Json -itemtype file -name file.json -value "Hello3" ;$objForm.close()
     }
 })
```